# Outputting one element in a loop when there is 1 in the list

Tags: python, list, loops, indexing

There is a task like this:

I have a list:

```
a = ["1", "2"]
```

And the for loop:

```
for i in range(0, 2):
    print(a[i])
```

But if the list is with one element:

```
a = ["1"]
```

then there will be an error:
IndexError: list index out of range

What can be done to keep the structure

```
for i in range(0, 2):
```

Comment: Why do you hard-code the range in the first place? This seems like an XY problem.

Comment: @Barmar I guess sometimes you just want to eyeball the first few elements of a list? A bit like doing .head() in pandas...

Comment: Where the code says `for i in range(0, 2):`, what exactly do you think this means? Why should it say `range(0, 2)`, and not any other numbers? Exactly what should happen when there is 1 item in the list? Exactly what should happen when there are **no** items in the list? Exactly what should happen when there are **more than two** items in the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle this  with a `try:except` block

```
a = ["1"]

for i in range(0, 2):
    try:
        print(a[i])
    except IndexError:
        break
```

But in general it's better to iterate over the list itself

```
for i in a:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over the list directly:

```
a = ["1", "2"]

for i in a:
    print(i)
```

If you specifically want to iterate over the indices of `a` rather than its elements (note that most of the time this is unnecessarily complicated and you shouldn't do it), build your `range` based on the `len` of `a` rather than specifying a hardcoded number like 2:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    print(a[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use `for` without `range`, but just with list instance, e.g.

```
print("list with many elements")
a = ["1","2","3"]
for i in a:
    print(i)
print("list with one element")
b = ["1"]
for i in b:
    print(i)
```

gives output

```
list with many elements
1
2
3
list with one element
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating over a range of indexes, iterate directly over a **slice** of the list. The useful thing here is that, for example, `lst[:10]` doesn't fail if the list has fewer than 10 elements - it just gives all the elements.

So in your case:

```
a = ["1"]
for x in a[:2]:
    print(x)
```

which prints just `1` as you intend.

This is one of many reasons why you should prefer loops like `for object in collection` instead of `for index in range_of_indexes`.